# How do you properly add paragraphs into a research paper?

Tags: style, formatting, mla

I'm writing an MLA formatted research paper and want to add the following into my paper.

> "Legislature
>
> The Legislative branch is Parliament, comprised of the Head of State and the Legislative Assembly.  Laws are enacted when Bills are passed by the Legislative Assembly, assented to by the Head of State and published in the Samoa Gazette (official Government newspaper, now known as the Savali Newspaper).  The Speaker of the Legislative Assembly is the chief presiding officer of Parliament.
>
> Executive
>
> Comprised of the Head of State and the Executive Government – of which the Prime Minister is head, supported by Cabinet Ministers.  The Executive Government is responsible for the day-to-day management of the State, including the enforcement of the laws of Samoa.
>
> Judiciary
>
> The Judiciary interprets the law, ensures that the rule of law prevails and is the guardian of the Constitution as the supreme law of Samoa.  The Chief Justice is the judicial and administrative head of the Judiciary." [1]

(This whole segment came from - [1] "The Government." Government of Samoa RSS. Web. 14 Oct. 2015. http://www.samoagovt.ws/about-government/#. )

---

I think it is all important information and can't find a way to shorten it, so I would like to add the entire section into my paper as is.

How do you properly add paragraphs into a research paper? Do they need to be in quotation marks or would you just cite where it came from?

I think this would also help others who may have similar questions.

Comment: I'm basically asking if your need to place "quotation marks" around the entire segment (like above) and site it [1]. Or if you can just site each paragraph without quotation marks [1]. Or if these are both wrong what is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something that big I would blockquote it (as you've done here for your post) and indent it, and then leave off quotes. It's not dialogue, which has specific practices for multiple paragraphs in a row, and I'd be worried that my reader would forget that I'm quoting someone.